# How do interim or partial transcripts work for application, and is it possible to have an admissions decision reversed based on the final version?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I attempted to be as detailed as I could in the title, but let me elaborate a bit more.

I'm sure this situation is common (if not normal) but I'm applying to PhD programs this year fall and will only have been done with half of my master's program by then.

In cases like this, would I submit the transcript for the first two semesters of my master's degree? If I were to receive an admission green light and confirm to enroll (which is usually around April I believe), is it common to have these decisions reversed if my final GPA were to fall?

Thanks for any feedback or tips.

Comment: Different universities may have different policies, but the usual policy is that, when you apply, you submit the transcript that your university can provide at that moment. The university that accepted you will probably want a copy of your final transcript when it becomes available, but in many cases they just check that your degree was awarded. Some universities might reverse the admission decision, but not just "if [your] final GPA were to fall".As far as I know, reversals like this would occur only if your performance crashed very dramatically.

Comment: Thanks for the extra perspective. I assume that usually someone in a similar situation as me would submit both bachelor's and master's transcripts? It only seems logical and commonsensical to do that but it's never specified in school websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explore this with the institutions you apply to.

And you need to read the correspondence carefully. If you get accepted, then you are probably accepted except in rare circumstances. But if you are "conditionally accepted" then you need to meet the conditions, whatever they are, to assure acceptance.

Acceptances are generated based on more that GPA, of course. Someone needs to make a prediction of success before one will be issued. But no prediction is perfect and students fail out even after enrolling. Universities know these things.

Tips and advice: Work hard. Don't let the bad things happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, the more I become immersed in research the more I'm realizing that my GPA might not be as important as I once thought it was. Regardless I was curious about how the process itself were to usually work, but it seems like it's got an institution-dependent factor to it.